# Nim FFI: Using existing type to wrap a C++ type

Tags: c++, c, ffi, nim-lang

I'm putting together a Nim wrapper for [Box2D](http://box2d.org/) using [`c2nim`](https://github.com/nim-lang/c2nim).

Box2D has its own mathematical vector class, [`b2Vec2`](https://github.com/erincatto/Box2D/blob/master/Box2D/Box2D/Common/b2Math.h#L53).  If I were using Box2D in raw C++, I'd just use that class.  Simple.

But Nim already has such functionality in the [`basic2d`](http://nim-lang.org/docs/basic2d.html) module's [`Vector2d`](http://nim-lang.org/docs/basic2d.html#Vector2d) type.

I want my wrapper's interface to use the built-in `Vector2d` type so that users of this wrapper don't have to mentally juggle two different vector types.  This entails somehow using `Vector2d` as a Nim interface to `b2Vec2`.  **How can I do this?**

**Things of note:**

- <s>Both `b2Vec2` and `Vector2d` are made of just two 32-bit `float`s.</s>  **I'm wrong.  Nim `float`s are 64-bit.**
- `Vector2d` is part of the Nim standard library, so I can't modify its definition.
- I'll create a wrapper for `b2Vec2` if I have to, but I'd like to avoid doing so, and I definitely don't want users to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it doesn't look like I can do this, at least not between `basic2d.Vector2d` and `b2Vec2`.  The former is made of two 64-bit floats, and the latter is made of two 32-bit floats.